# ubuntu 14.04 can't install on my dell inpiron mini 1012

Tags: boot

I tried installing the latest version of kubuntu and tried ubuntu 14.04 too. I   tried booting it via USB but i do not know why I cant install it. the ubuntu logo   will show up then i'll choose "install ubuntu" and my screen will show many texts   and it says something like this

`[     9.895886] ---[end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(2,O)`

I cant really understand this. I have watched videos regarding installing ubuntu via USB and follow properly but it just do not work for me. please help me my laptop is really slow and I think of trying ubuntu for study purposes

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu or Kubuntu 14.04 and later will be quite slow on this hardware. Please try Xubuntu or even Lubuntu 14.04. They are much more lightweight on resources.

You may try as well to change the boot options. When the ubuntu logo appears, press F6, then use space key to enable "acpi=off". If that doesn't work, you may try the other options from that menu as well.
You may read more about boot options here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions